# Where can I look for post-doctoral positions in Europe?

Tags: phd, postdocs, job

I am about to submit my PhD thesis and I will be starting to apply for post-doctoral positions, and I was wondering if you can advise me on where to look all the opportunities available in Europe. I know how to find them in the UK

Comment: Europe is vast, and an answer would probably be more helpful if you specific in which field you are. For example, some websites may only be for "postdocs in field X in country Y" (e.g. the French math society has a website with all the math postdocs available, etc).

Comment: Euraxess is probably an option. There are also field-specific mailing lists, such as "CHI-JOBS" for Human-Computer Interaction where people all across the world (and Europe) advertise there.

Other than that, you might want to look at the job vacancies of specific universities that you are interested in.

Comment: I am doing my PhD in Health Sciences focusing on skin health. I would like to stay in this field but also considering my Biomedical background I am also considering relevant positions

Comment: @TheWanderer Thank you for your reply. I will look at the Universities that interest me.

Comment: If you are in math, then your question is a duplicate of https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/970/19627 The answers to this question can be useful even if you're not in Math.

Comment: In the UK: jobs.ac.uk

Answer (score 2):

More information is always helpful.  Most students who do postdocs find them in the following ways.

1) A recommendation to a company or university from the faculty of their current institution.

2) A recently graduated Ph.D. student who may know of a great fit for you at their new postdoc.

3) A place you've interned in the past that is open to bringing you on as a postdoc.

4) University mailing list for graduate students in your field.

5) Your academic network you build from all those years attending conferences and presenting your work.