# Is there any website for postdoc jobs in Canada?

Tags: postdocs, job-search, canada

In Europe there is https://www.euraxess.de or in the Netherlands there is https://www.academictransfer.com/en/ to find postdoc positions.

Are there any similar website to find postdoc positions in Canada?

I only could find https://jobs.sciencecareers.org. I am wondering if there are any more websites.

Comment: Some universities use https://academicjobsonline.org/ajo , but it is not the norm. I got the posting for mine from a specific field newsletter. AFAIK, nothing as organized as we would want it to be (same thing for TT jobs btw).

Comment: Which field are you in?

Comment: @PieterNaaijkens I have a master in theoretical physics and a PhD in experimental Biophysics. 
I am mainly looking for mathematical modelling in biology. I would like the postdoc to be focused on mathematics and computation with application in biology.

Comment: @MOON In that case you may find some relevant positions on mathjobs.org, but I am not quite sure how complete it will be.

Comment: This question is borderline a duplicate of https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/970/postdoc-opportunities-in-mathematics/96800#96800. I would recommend reading [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/96800/19627)

Comment: @Clément That answer is specifically for math jobs. I would like to have a website for a broader range of fields.

Comment: I disagree with closing as "shopping". OP is not asking for people to give job listings themselves, but rather for *links* to job listing. Straight from the description on meta: "*In most cases, the closest, on-topic question would be on **how to find** a journal, university, topic, or similar*": this is exactly what OP is asking!

Comment: Is the Netherlands in Europe?

Comment: @SolarMike Yes! What do you exactly mean by that?

Comment: @MOON Just interesting that you use Europe for .de then mention Netherlands by name...

Comment: @SolarMike That website has other ending domains too. The `de` gives the jobs for other countries too. That's why I did not bother to change it. The website I mentioned for the Netherlands only shows the jobs in the Netherlands.

Comment: @SolarMike Euraxess, as its name indicates, is a Europe-wide website. The main website is there: https://euraxess.ec.europa.eu/

Answer (score 3):

I am one of the editors of https://www.thePostdoctoral.com - We had keywords "mathematical modelling biology" - last time May 2018 (https://promiseagep.com/2018/04/30/post-doctoral-research-associate-mathematical-biology/). There were 3 more in April and January.

Up to 250 new postdoc positions every day. We search the web AND social media and cover almost all webpages. Once they post or announce it's in our data base, before being shown in search engines.

If you want to have access to our data base simply sign up. Our power function is an archive keyword search (up 365 days, makes sense for 30 days or so).

Hope this helps.

Good luck and all the best,
Anthony from thePostdoctoral.com (and https://nextPhD.com and https://PhDvibe.com)

Answer (score 2):

One Canada specific possibility is: [University Affairs](https://www.universityaffairs.ca/search-job/) although this is far from universal. Canadian positions are also often found on international databases.

Ultimately if you are looking for a funded position you will probably need to hunt down/contact individual PIs.

You may be eligible for Post-Doctoral fellowships through [NSERC](http://www.nserc-crsng.gc.ca/Students-Etudiants/PD-NP/index_eng.asp) for Sciences/Engineering or [SSHRC](http://www.sshrc-crsh.gc.ca/funding-financement/index-eng.aspx) for Social Sciences and Humanities.

Comment: I found https://scholarshipdb.net/ is really good too.